# "GUI design" and "user interface" tags should be synonyms

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

...because non-graphical user interface questions like "how can I make my bank's phone service maze of options less homicide-inducing" belong on UX.SE

I reckon user-interface should point to GUI design. Let's also merge in any other UI/UX tags while we're at it, and add something like:

> For questions about UI or UX design that are not related to designing graphics, please
>   ask at http://ux.stackexchange.com

How do we make it happen?

Comment: I agree with this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Done!**

We can always make improvements, but so far we have:

- Created a new tag called [interface-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interface-design)
- Merged into it the previously existing tags [ui](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ui), [user-interface](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-interface), [interface](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interface) and [gui-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui-design)

Feel free to suggest changes!

Answer (score 1):

Good catch. If you have 5 or more rep in the tag, have at it yourself: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms.

In short, you can propose synonyms when you have a total of 5 rep in the tag you propose a synonym for, and your total rep is at least 2,500. Everyone with 5+ total rep in the tag gets to vote, and with 4 votes, the proposal is accepted.

Comment: Just tried, it gave a weird error message *"Reverse synonym user-interface already proposed on the tag ui"*. No idea what a reverse synonym is or why that would block this. Looks like we have a small heap of UI and UX related tags though... Can someone who understands the system please sort it out...

Comment: @user568458 [tag:user-interface] is the current catch-all for [tag:ui] and [tag:interface]. Could you try and propose to merge [tag:gui-design] into [tag:user-interface] instead of the other way around? Or is that what you did?

Comment: Just thinking out loud here, but would "interface design" be a more self-explanatory term? I wonder if "user-interface" (correct as it is) is clear enough, or if it's too technical.

Comment: I second any notion by our dictatrix @Yisela :)

Comment: Yeah "interface design" is an actual branch of design so that make sense. So can someone who knows what they're doing create interface design, include the 'when to use UX.SE instead' comment in the summary, and merge everything else into it?

Comment: Done! I merged user-interface and ui into **interface-design**. I didn't touch GUI design. Should we also merge / "synonymize" it?